# Calculate the day when Date is given as input using the Doomsday algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, datetime, reinventing-the-wheel

Was too bored in holidays...here's a code which finds the day of the week using the algorithm in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=714LTMNJy5M). Please give a logical date in the correct format cause I didn't account for improper inputs cause I'm too lazy. My code is short and sweet.

```
day=["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"]    #some database numbers and strings
mdoom=[3,28,14,4,9,6,11,8,5,10,7,12]
while True:
    entry=input('\nEnter a date in DD/MM/YYYY format:')         #Input date in a specified format
    date,month,year = map(int,entry.split('/'))                 #Get the date,month and year
    centdoom=[3,2,0,5]
    a=centdoom[((year//100)%4)-3]
    b=(year%100)//12
    c=(year%100)%12
    d=c//4                                                      #Random calculations for doomsday :)
    e=a+b+c+d

    if (year%4==0) and ((year%100!=0) or (year%400==0)):        #Checks for leap year
        mdoom[0],mdoom[1]=4,29

    ddoom=e%7                                                   #finds a date in the 1st week which has the same day as the doomsday    
    r=mdoom[month-1]                                            #Gives the doomsdate in the input month 
    r=r%7
    r=ddoom-r                                                   
    date=date%7                                                 #finds a date in the 1st week which has the same day as the input date
    print('\n',day[(r+date)%7])                                 #prints the output
    k=input('\nTry again?(y/n)')
    if k=='y':
        continue
    else:
        break
```

And any suggestions or improvements are welcome.

Comment: I would slightly improve on leap year (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year#Algorithm).

Comment: can you please send the edited part of the leap year condition...cause I can't plug in the 2 new conditions according to Wiki in my code.....I'm a complete noob   :(  ...thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Your code is hard to understand, even after watching the video.

1. Make some functions. `years_doomsday` would help move some of the hard to understand information to be self-contained.
2. If you need to floor divide and get the remainder use `divmod`.
3. You can check the leap year using `calendar.isleap`.
4. You have a bug, if you ever enter a leap year then the non-leap years will return incorrect values for January and February.
5. You should make a function that calls `years_doomsday`, and returns the weekday.
6. You should make `centdoom` a global constant.
7. By rotating `centdoom` once you can remove the need for the `-3`.

```
import calendar

WEEKDAYS = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"]
MDOOMSDAY = [3, 28, 14, 4, 9, 6, 11, 8, 5, 10, 7, 12]
MDOOMSDAY_LEAP = list(MDOOMSDAY)
MDOOMSDAY_LEAP[:2] = [4, 29]
CDOOMSDAY = [2, 0, 5, 3]


def years_doomsday(year):
    a, b = divmod(year, 100)
    c, d = divmod(b, 12)
    e = d // 4
    return (CDOOMSDAY[a % 4] + c + d + e) % 7


def doomsday(year, month, day):
    y_doomsday = years_doomsday(year)
    mdoomsday = MDOOMSDAY_LEAP if calendar.isleap(year) else MDOOMSDAY
    return WEEKDAYS[(day - mdoomsday[month-1] + y_doomsday) % 7]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    tests = [
        (2305, 7, 13, 'Thursday'),
        (1776, 7, 4, 'Thursday'),
        (1969, 7, 20, 'Sunday'),
        (1984, 1, 6, 'Friday'),
        (1902, 10, 19, 'Sunday'),
    ]
    for test in tests:
        if doomsday(*test[:3]) != test[-1]:
            print('Broken for', test)
```

If you don't want any fun, you can replace your code with `datetime.date.isoweekday`.

```
import datetime

for test in tests:
    if WEEKDAYS[datetime.date(*test[:3]).isoweekday()%7] != test[-1]:
        print('Broken for', test)
```

Comment: Nice answer! +1

Comment: why not do `tests = [(2705, 7, 13), "Thursday",...]` or even making it a dict, and then `for date, answer in tests:if doormsday(*date) != answer:print(...)`; and I find your way of assembling `MDOOMSDAY_LEAP` rather strange

Comment: @MaartenFabré Because I find `((1, 2, 3), 'd')` is more annoying to type then `(1, 2, 3, 'd')`.

Comment: it is 2 more brackets to type, yes, but a lot more clearer when using the test

Comment: @MaartenFabré And I was testing this in IDLE where I kept having to write the same stuff over and over.

Comment: 1.Thanks for the neater version of the code...2.divmod method is pretty awesome..3.I want to keep the sanity of my code (i don't want to add modules like calender)...that's why the leap year was found using simple 3 conditions..4.my code doesn't have a bug,if u read my code..I find the leap year and rectify of Jan and feb...5.thanks for the shorter code..just lovely...